# How to programmatically access pre-loaded fonts

Tags: android, android-downloadable-fonts

I have mentioned pre-loaded fonts details as meta data in Android Manifest(as per the section **Pre-declaring fonts in the manifest** of [Downloadable Fonts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts#downloading-fonts)). I am able to use pre-loaded font in .xml file by  app:fontFamily="@font/aladin" (here, xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto")

But whenever I try to access pre-loaded font programmatically, I am getting the below exception:
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Font resource ID #0x7f090000

Code Snippet to access pre-loaded font:
    textView.setTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.aladin));

Any help or guidance will be well appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

If you have stored the font in resources

```
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.custom);
Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/HandmadeTypewriter.ttf");
tv.setTypeface(face);
```

Your error indicates that you got some reference wrong, so you should check your references

Comment: Hi Toby, thanks for the quick reply. But here I want to use Downloadable Fonts by Pre-declaring fonts in the manifest(https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts#downloading-fonts)